# I want to pop my view from particular view but it works like LIFO

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontroller

i am using navigation based application but i want to pop my view from any of the view i want but it always work like LIFO, what i can do? Is it possible in iPhone ,If it is possible then help me.. I am using this code for pop my view

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at the class documentation for [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Instead of just popping a single view controller, you can:

- Pop to a specific view controller with `popToViewController:animated:`
- Pop all the way to the root with `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`
- Set a brand new stack of view controllers with `setViewControllers:animated:`

All of these will be automatically animated (if specified) and avoid the "LIFO" method of operation you describe.